# Basic ReactJS Components routing

Tags: react.js, jsx

Recently I've started learning ReactJS and I do not look forward to making one Page website so I learned about `react-router` and this is my way of doing to it.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "babel-polyfill";
import Navbar from "./Components/MenuNavbar";
import Footer from "./Components/Bottom";
import Home from "./Components/Home";
import About from "./Components/About";
import Contact from "./Components/Contact";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import Products from "./Components/Products";
import { CircleArrow as ScrollUpButton } from "react-scroll-up-button";
// import Topbar from "./Components/Topbar";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/products" component={Products} />
              <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            </Switch>
            <ScrollUpButton />
            <Footer />
          </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In my other Components, I wrap parent in a `div` as learned in some tutorials, like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div id="products">
        <ProductsHero />
        <ProductsCashew />
        <ProductsAlmonds />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Is this the best practice? If not how can I improve? Shall I wrap every child in `React.Fragment` instead of `div`? If so why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether to use `React.Fragment` or not depends on how you want the resulting DOM structured. Using `React.Fragment` avoids introducing additional elements in the DOM when they are not needed.

Fragments were introduced because only one React element can be returned from the `render` function, but it is pretty common and natural to need to return more than one element. Before Fragments, we had to wrap these elements in a `div` or other tag that really served no other purpose than to please React. This worked most of the time, but there were cases where it was not sufficient, such as when a component needed to return two `tr` elements. Wrapping `tr`'s in a `div` and trying to place that in a `tbody` doesn't work. With Fragments, multiple elements can be returned and React does not have to render anything for the Fragment itself, only the children of the Fragment.

That being said, there are some situations where wrapping elements in a `div` or other tag makes sense. One that comes up frequently for me is when I have a component just like your products example, but I want to apply a margin, padding, border, or other style to the wrapper around the actual children. In that case, `React.Fragment` can't help me and I need a `div` or `section`.

A general rule-of-thumb, if you have a `div` or `section` that is doing absolutely nothing but letting you return multiple elements, you should switch it out with `React.Fragment`. If you are using that wrapper `div` in any way, keep it.

If you haven't yet, I would suggest reading the official [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) guide. It demonstrates the table situation as an example for why Fragments were introduced.